# how can I achieve this, I don't want ipad voiceover to read <h5>abc<h5> as "abc heading level 5" but I just want it to read "abc"

Tags: html, accessibility

IPAD voice over is reading `<h5>abc<h5>` as "abc heading level 5" but I don't want that but instead I just want it to read "abc", how can I achieve this

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also read [How much research effort is expected from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/18254155).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use another html tag. `<h1> -> <h6>` is header tags and will be announced as header. `<button>` will be announce as button, `<li>` will be announced as list. You can use another tag and add the  css:

```
<span class="set-your-class-here">abc <span>
```

```
.set-your-class-here{
 display: block;
  font-size: .83em;
  margin-top: 1.67em;
  margin-bottom: 1.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out one another way, if I use role="presentation", Ipad vocieover ignores the schematics of header tags, so we can achive the same without changing markup